# Can i use spring exception translation without using spring-managed-transaction?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-transactions

I'm developing with JPA 2 and Spring 3.

I'm using the @Repository for my Dao classes hoping that i could make use of the Spring exception translation.

But the problem is, i'm not using the spring managed transaction (no @Transactional, no definition of transactionManager in my spring config file), but a custom transaction handling for my JPA apps.

Is it still possible somehow to make use of the translation from my custom transaction manager ? The implementation of this custom transaction manager is still using the EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager from JPA.

Please share your thoughts.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

If you use @Repository annotation, you will get Spring translated exception, whether you use spring transaction manager or not :

[image]

But of course, you won't get the Spring exceptions which would be thrown by the Spring transaction manager itself.

Comment: but when i look into my sql exception thrown, it all happens when the transaction is being commited. the exception itself doesnt exactly happen in the Dao classes. how can spring translate the exception that is not thrown from it's own transaction manager ?

Comment: Any exception is managed by the transaction manager (which could trigger a rollback) but the translation occurs before.